# Can I embed WP User Registration form on another website?

Tags: wordpress, user-registration

I have two WordPress website on the same topic. Example- A.com and SimilarToA.com I want to use only A.com registration even when the user fills the form on SimilarToA.com. Is this possible?

Can I embed WP User registration on another website?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't. but you could try this solution,

1. choose your primary registration site.
2. when the new user try to register to your "other than" primary site redirect it to your primary registration site.
3. you could add new user via code so when new user registered on your primary site, send api request to your secondary site to add new wp user. (ofcourse you need create an APi handler on your secondary site).

~[sandree.com](http://sandree.com)~